# noticed variations of %1$s being used in code, cannot google escaped charecters. Please link a resource

Tags: java

```
String.format("com.dummy.%1$s.", strVarName)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the documentation on `Formatter` available [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).